# Automatically deleting the cached password in an iOS app

Tags: ios, caching, passwords

I am creating an iOS app for iPad. One of the requirements says: *The System is automatically deleting the cached password an enduser has entered when the application is in background.* As I am very new with Objective-C and with the iOS world, I have no clue of how to access the cache from code (or if it is even possible) and to delete the password contained on it.

Anyone with a better understanding of all this?

Comment: You need to know how and where the password is stored. It should be in the keychain. Or do you actually have a cookie or something which is representative of the login session but isn't actually a password?

Comment: Thanks for replying. It is stored in a keychain. The thing is that as part of another requirement I am supposed to remove the keychain's data from memory when the app goes to the background. So, if I do that, I would actually be deleting the password from cache, or am I wrong?

Comment: Removing it from the keychain could be considered as removing it from cache (assuming it isn't stored anywhere else).

Comment: Ok, the same as I thought, thanks a lot!